# Insert current date in column name

Tags: powerquery

I'm starting to use Power Query in Excel 365 (desktop install).  Is there a way to change the column name to append or prepend today's date to the column name?  If the column is named "Size" I'd like the column to be named "Size_2019_04_18".  The exact format of the date doesn't matter.

Comment: i don't know about Power Query, but VBA can do this pretty easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1, Go to **Power Query Editor**

2, Go to **Advanced Editor**

[image]

3, add the code below (Case Sentitive):

```
Let
   ...
   NewName = "Size_"&Date.ToText(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow())),
   #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Sheet1_Table,{{"Size", Int64.Type}}),
   #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Size", NewName}})

in
   #"Renamed Columns"
```

Test Result:
[image]

Comment: Follow-up question to this.  Whenever the data is refreshed now the date changes to the current date, which makes sense.  Is there a way using Power Query to make the date stick after it is applied?  I don't want it refreshed after the initial calculation.  So if it gets set to 5/6/2019 on 5/6, when I refresh the data on 5/8 it's changing to 5/8/2019.  I would like it to stay at 5/6/2019.

Comment: @Jason This is a different question. You want to keep the first occurrence since the column name is changing by time, am I right? Please ask one question separately.

Comment: Thanks for replaying.  I did create a new question. [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56084559/having-values-persist-in-column-names)