# Having values persist in column names?

Tags: excel, powerquery

Thanks to another Stack Overflow user I'm able to capture today's date and insert it into my column headers.  However each time I refresh the data it refreshes the date.  Is there a way using Power Query to make the date stick after it is applied? I don't want it refreshed after the initial calculation. So if it gets set to 5/6/2019 on 5/6, when I refresh the data on 5/8 it's changing to 5/8/2019. I would like it to stay at 5/6/2019.

Here is the code that was provided to insert the dates:

```
Let
   ...
   NewName = "Size_"&Date.ToText(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow())),
   #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Sheet1_Table,{{"Size", Int64.Type}}),
   #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Size", NewName}})

in
   #"Renamed Columns"
```

Comment: I wonder why not just type it? The reason is you only need the 'column name+today's date' once. Then you do not want it to change anymore.

Comment: @GenWan I'm beginning to think that that is approach I need to take.  Or run the CSV through VBA first before loading it in Power Query.